# Удаленное перемещение файлов по сети через Telnet

Tags: lan

Здравствуйте.

Возможно ли перекинуть файлы с одного сегмента сети на другой через Telnet?То есть пишем в командной строке **telnet [ip]** и далее после подключения по средствам каких то команд скопировать файлы на компьютер с данным ip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно. Только более стильной модной молодежной утилитой nc (netcat). На хосте куда шлете

> nc -l -p 2222 > file

А откуда шлете

> cat file | nc serverip 2222

Там конечно еще можно ключей накидать, что б не пришлось ctrl^c нажимать, и всякие там таймауты, но это уже вы сами в доках найдет. Главное принцип понять.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую, жаль не могу палец вверх поставить за ответ.

Comment: я могу )))